# "File not found" when restoring deleted directory in Subversion

Tags: svn

I wanted to roll back my project to an earlier stage, so I tried this:

```
svn rm -m "clear out mistakes rolling back" ^/MyProject/trunk
svn copy -m "roll back" -r 165 ^/MyProject/trunk ^/MyProject/trunk
```

But I kept getting the error "File not found: revision 265, path '/MyProject/trunk'".  265 is HEAD, but I don't know why it would be looking for the target directory in an existing revision, rather than simply creating it.

Apparently the problem was with the ^ notation, because using complete URLs worked OK:

```
svn copy -m "roll back" <full URL>/MyProject/trunk@165 <full URL>/MyProject/trunk
```

But I've used the ^ notation recently to make a branch via a similar copy operation.  (The client is command-line svn 1.6.17.)  So, why did it not work in this case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem is with "-r " and "@rev": they have different meaning.

`-r rev <path>` ---  operative revision --- means the state in which was @HEAD was at revision "rev" (e.g. if @HEAD doesn't exist the command fails; if it was replaced/copied from some path2 in revision > rev, then the state is path2@rev)

`path@rev` ---peg revision --- means the state of path exactly at revision rev (then it doesn't matter if path exists at HEAD, and even if path@HEAD is replaced from path2, the state is path@rev).

See more here http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.6/svn.advanced.pegrevs.html

Comment: Fascinating -- I had always vaguely assumed that `@rev` was an abbreviation for `-r rev`, but peg revisions are more subtle.

Comment: To put it differently: when locating an old item, the default peg revision is BASE or HEAD, and the default operative revision is the peg revision.  So, although people recommend using either `-r` or `@` to restore old items, it appears that `@` is required to restore an item which doesn't currently exist.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to delete that file and add a new file with a new name(even a single character change in name will work). would get updated in repository then.