# svn: File not found when merging deleted branch

Tags: svn

When I try to use a deleted branch as a merge source, I get an error that the branch does not exist in the current version:

```
svn merge -r100:105 svn://repository/project/branches/deletedbranch .
```

The output is:

```
svn: File not found: revision 110, path '/branches/deletedbranch'
```

But the branch was deleted between its last edit and the current revision. How do I bypass this error?

Comment: I just found the answer while digging through this question about restoring a deleted directory: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11595052/file-not-found-when-restoring-deleted-directory-in-subversion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can append @rev to the end of the source URL using a revision when the branch did exist:

```
svn merge -r100:105 svn://repository/project/branches/deletedbranch@100 .
```

This is called a "peg revision" and tells SVN to use the path as it existed in revision 100. This can also be used to point to a version of a directory or file which has since been replaced with a different directory or file of the same name.